# Изъятия текста из диалогового окна (winApi)

Tags: winapi, c++, visual-c++

Почему, когда я считываю текст из BoxEditor диалогового окна, или же вызываю диалог открытия/сохранения файла, то текст у меня сохраняется в элементы с четными индексами?

Например, что бы считать текст из боксЭдитора мне требуется такой код

```
                string s="";
                char text[50];
                GetDlgItemText(hDlg,IDC_X,LPWSTR(text), 50);
                s+=text[0];
                s+=text[2];
                s+=text[4];
                s+=text[6];
```

подскажите, Пожалуйста, как считать текст, что бы он заполнял весь массив, а не лишь его элементы с четными индексами.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Потому что нужно использовать соответствующие типы строковых переменных. В Windows используются символы однобайтные и двухбайтные. Сделано так для поддержки Unicode и многоязычности. LPWSTR - это как раз и есть строка из двухбайтных символов, char [] - строка из однобайтных.

Comment: Да, спасибо!
Вы мне объяснили почему так! 

А решил я свою проблему используя несколько другую функцию:
GetDlgItemTextA(hDlg,IDC_Y,LPSTR(text), 50);

Comment: Тоже правильно. Многие ф-ции в WinAPI существуют в двух вариантах. GetDlgItemTextA и GetDlgItemTextW - один из примеров таких функций. A и W как раз и указывают на тип использованных символов/строк. A = ASCII (1-байтные символы), W = Wide (2-хбайтные, "как бы" Unicode).